# Authorization token on on puppet "SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK"

Tags: puppet

I am creating a autorization  token in puppet to setup code manager config in puppet master. On executing command and on putting login user and password
"puppet-access login --service-url https://10.20.1.4:4433/rbac-api --lifetime 365"
I got the error below

"Unable to reach the RBAC server at https://10.20.1.4:4433/rbac-api/v1/auth/token due to the following error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK."

could any one please help on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was connecting puppet with the  wrong URL. the certificate was on hostname, rather then on the IP. I changed the url to https://MYHOSTNAME:4433/rbac-api and it worked.

Thanks